# button click or copy paste with Python's requests

Tags: python

I want to do a button click or copy-paste with "request" like selenium
but as far as i know it can't on request

Is there no way?

selenium is too slow ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` is read-only.  It does not construct the DOM. If the button click triggers a new request, then you can formulate your own GET or POST request that simulates it.